# How to build installers for .NET Core app?

Tags: asp.net-core, installation, electron.net

I develop my NET Core app+Electron.NET. It is cross-platform app.
How to build installers for .NET Core app for Windows? Linux? Mac OS? What tool to use?

Comment: I am afriad it is impossible. In general, for deploying .net application, we use windows installer and clickonce, both of them only works under windows enviroment, you could not use them for mac. For .net core, it is corss-platform, but as far as i know, there is no official installer to support deploy .net core to any platform, you may consider deploy your project by docker, and then use docker image from windows, linux and mac.

Comment: Ok, thnx, I see - no one universal tool. For Windows;ClickOnce, what tool can be used for Linux, what tool for Mac OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Electron.NET version **5.22.12**, they switched to **electron builder**. An installer will be created automatically here. The settings can be made in the **electron.manifest.json** file. The documentation of the settings can be found at https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

The information about the migration can be found on the start page at the bottom:
https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET

Comment: Thanx Gregor, great to know!